# In Ext JS, how to get the value of the combo box item index?

Tags: javascript, extjs5

if we know the index of the combo box item, how do we get the value of it in ext js? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If we know the index of the item, and let's assume `valueField` is `id` set to `combobox`, we can find it like below:

```
comboBox.getStore().getAt(3).get('id'); // assuming `index = 3`
```